# How can I get a script of a game from this site's REST API

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I'm a python beginner.
and please understand my poor English, I'm not good at it.

I am trying to download a script of game from a site's rest API in order to use my English learning material.

API address is below

https://trailsinthedatabase.com/rest-api-docs#operation/getDetail

If I want to get all script of 'Trails in the sky the 3rd'
(I guess gameId is 3, and one of fname is 'c0301')

How can I get the script?

I googled how to do API and tried to do it on my own but I can just download some...I don't know what that was.

my code is below.

```
import requests
import json

parameter = {'gameId' : 3, "fname" : "c0301" }

response = requests.get("https://trailsinthedatabase.com/rest-api-docs#operation/getDetail", params=parameter)

data = response.text
```

please...help me.

Comment: the link you've provided is a documentation for the API, not the API itself
the api endpoints are under `/api` routes

So you probably should do 

`response = requests.get(f"https://trailsinthedatabase.com/api/script/detail/{gameId}/{fname}/")`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make my comment more readable

the link you've provided is a documentation for the API, not the API itself the api endpoints are under /api routes So you probably should do

```
import requests
import json

gameId = 3
fname = "c0301"

response = requests.get("https://trailsinthedatabase.com/api/script/detail/{gameId}/{fname}")

data = response.text
```

data will now contain plain text response, you could also use

```
data = response.json()
```

If you need to perform further actions with data itself

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I run the code you wrote above received status code 400. Anyway thank you! I'll try to find way to solve it.